# Python doesn't import a module from another folder inside of parent folder

Tags: python, import, module, path

I am having so much trouble with imports and I never know how to solve them.
The folders of the project are arranged as follows

```
project:
   distributed_computing:
       agent_server.py
   kinematics:
       inverse_kinematics.py
```

I am trying to import inverse_kinematics into agent_server.py.

The code used for that is :

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..', 'kinematics'))

from kinematics import inverse_kinematics
```

I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kinematics'.

Following [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-module-from-different-directory/) I also tried to modify PYTHONPATH by adding the whole path `C:\Users\TheCh\.......\project` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0):

The script should not worry about modifying `sys.path`. It should *assume* that it will be executed in an environment where the top-level package `kinematics` is located in a directory in `sys.path`. That's what

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project python /path/to/agent_server.py
```

does, no matter what the current working directory is.